# Deleting colon while using \renewcommand for table names

Tags: tables, captions

I have to rename one of the many tables as Fig. But executing the below script resulted in ':' before the caption.

```
\renewcommand{\tablename}{}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{}

\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{center}

% table contents

\end{center}
\caption{Fig 1: Frame description}
\label{table1}
\end{table}
```

The caption of the table looked like this- : Fig 1: Frame description.

Is there a way to make the initial ':' disappear?

Comment: Instead of using the `table` environment, just wrap it in a `figure` environment, then you don't have to worry about adjusting the caption detail. The contents within a `figure` environment can still be anything (need not necessarily be a figure). Strange..., but perfectly normal.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you give us a complete small document; in particular the documentclass and other packages will affect how to answer this question.  You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) for further help.

Comment: Use `\centering` instead of the `center` environment inside a `table`; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following is what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[figureposition=bottom]{caption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{horse}{\enskip}
\captionsetup{
  font=small,
  labelfont=sc,
  labelsep=horse,
  width=0.5\textwidth
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\caption{Fish}
\label{fish}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: And you are not allowed to use the University seal in this context ;-), http://medarbejdere.au.dk/administration/kommunikation/branding/designmanualen/hentfiler/segl/regler/, better to just use `\rule{5cm}{5cm}`

Comment: @daleif Sorry. `:(` I'll choose `\rule{5cm}{5cm}`.

Comment: no worries, they do put it online, but most people does not bother to read the fine print.